# The image data generated an overflow during processing: WriteableBitmap WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bitmap

```
WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(300000, 300000, 300, 300, PixelFormats.Rgb24, null);


System.OverflowException: 'The image data generated an overflow during processing.'
```

I'm creating a WriteableBitmap and it just throws this error. When I try to reduce the pixelWidth and pixelHeight by a factor of 100 the error goes. What should I do ?

Error Stack Trace:

```
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap..ctor(Int32 pixelWidth, Int32 pixelHeight, Double dpiX, Double dpiY, PixelFormat pixelFormat, BitmapPalette palette)
   at WriteableBitmap_DMC.MainWindow.Init() in WriteableBitmap-DMC\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 33
   at WriteableBitmap_DMC.MainWindow.MainWindow_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in WriteableBitmap-DMC\WriteableBitmap-DMC\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 29
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastEvent(DependencyObject root, RoutedEvent routedEvent)
   at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastLoadedEvent(Object root)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireLoadedPendingCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.Resize(ICompositionTarget resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.OnResize()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
```

Comment: What do you plan on doing with a 300,000 pixel square bitmap?

Comment: See the BitmapSource [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#remarks): *The maximum height and width of an image is 2^16 pixels...*

Comment: I will have a list of points for which I'll have to give them a color. I just realized how stupid it would be to color a single pixel out of 300,000^2. I'll scale it down to some value and do it.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/58710bdd-4832-4531-a50a-b83a7e733cdd/maximum-size-of-a-writeablebitmap-systemwindowsmediaimagingwritablebitmap?forum=wpf) you are significantly exceeding the maximum size of the bitmap:

> The maximum height and width of an image is 2^16 pixels at 32 bits per channel * 4 channels. The maximum size of a BitmapSource is 2^32 bytes (64 gigabytes) and the maximum image size is four gigapixels.

300000 is much larger than 2^16. There would be 90 gigapixels and a total size of 270 gigabytes. So you are exceeding the size on all criteria.

Managing such large image files would be cumbersome to say the least. So the common method to handle very large images is to split them into smaller chunks and render the chunks size by side. Say chunks of 2048x2048 for a compromise between file size and file count.